# PANDAS groupby 2 columns then count and mean

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame of users and each time they entered a website, it looks like this:

(if there are x row with same week and date it means the user entered the site x time that date).

| ID | week | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 20/07/21 |
| 2 | 3 | 23/07/21 |
| 2 | 3 | 23/07/21 |
| 2 | 3 | 26/07/21 |
| 2 | 4 | 30/07/21 |
| 2 | 4 | 30/07/21 |
| 2 | 4 | 30/07/21 |
| 2 | 4 | 31/07/21 |

so far I've managed to do this:

| ID | week | date | days number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 20/07/21 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 23/07/21 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | 26/07/21 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | 30/07/21 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 | 31/07/21 | 1 |

using this code:

```
df.groupby(['ID','week','date']).agg({'date':['count']})
```

but I need to calculate the mean times each user used the site by week, so each user has a row for each week. Therefor the output I need looks like this:

| ID | week | mean days number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 1.5 |
| 2 | 4 | 2 |

Any ideas how to continue?

Thanks!!

Comment: Add another `groupby.mean`, do you want to use only one step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
(df.groupby(['ID', 'week', 'date'], as_index=False)['date']
 .agg('count')
 .groupby(['ID', 'week'], as_index=False)
 .agg(**{'mean days number': ('date', 'mean')})
)
```

Output:

```
   ID  week  mean days number
0   1     2               1.0
1   2     3               1.5
2   2     4               2.0
```